# How to turn off constraint lines drawn using OpenGL render?

Tags: rendering, animation, opengl

When rendering my animation with OpenGL Render instead of the normal Render I see it's wonderfully extremely fast.

But it draws object linking lines in each frame that normal render doesn't. How do I turn these off please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In properties panel, turn off Relationship Lines under Display (or better, select Only Render). Guess, OpenGL uses the same render engine used by material viewport shading.